# How to detect http status code in angular 2

Tags: angular, httpresponse

I have a loadSize() func in my angular2 project and it calls a getTotalNumberCampaigns() in my service and return a observable. and I subscribe to  this observable to get the result.

this is my loadSize()

```
   loadSize() {
    this.campaignsService.getTotalNumberCampaigns().subscribe(value => {//async call
        this.campaignSize = value;
    }, (err)=> {}

    );
}
```

let's say there is an error with my getTotalNumberCampaigns() and it will fire the err=>{} in subscribe. My question is **how do i know what the httpreponse status code is** so that i can direct the user to take different action (if it is connection failed(502), the user should refresh. if it is access_token expiry(500), the page should be jump to login page)

this is my getTotalNumberCampaigns in service class

```
 getTotalNumberCampaigns(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/Count`, { headers: this.headers })
        .map<number>(res => <number>res.json())
}
```

[image: why i get 200]

Comment: it should be on err.status, check [angular response](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html)

Comment: My getTotalNumberCampaigns() function returns a observable of NUMBER type. don't know if error happened,does it still return an observable of number? should I change it to Observable<any>?

Comment: No you don't need to change the observable type. The observable type will not change.

Comment: you could change the error callback to :  (err:any) => console.log(err.status)

Comment: Thanks, but i got 200 instead of 500. it should be 500 (access_token expiry). see my latest picture

Comment: The error in your picture is caused by a preflight request (option) request that is made before your get request.So it's not thrown by the same observable returned from http.get().  It is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) related error, it's not (access_token) error. You should add the header : (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) to your server.

Comment: everything works fine before my access_token expired. any idea how to catch the 500 error in my frontend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104971/discussion-between-abdulrahman-and-bob-zhang).

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33942337/3582411 helped me
might consider takinga look at it

Answer (score 6):

The returned error corresponds to the response itself, so you can use its status attribute to get the status code:

```
loadSize() {
    this.campaignsService.getTotalNumberCampaigns().subscribe(value => {//async call
        this.campaignSize = value;
    }, (err: any) => { console.log(err.status); console.log(err);}

    );
}
```

Comment: Strange. Do you use the catch operator previously in your data flow? The response object is provided when an error occurs. But you're free to catch it with this operator and use Objectable.throw to throw another one then. Is it your case?

Comment: I will start a new question since for this topic the question has already solved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718175/why-my-error-in-subscirbe-err-here-is-different-from-the-error-in-bro

Answer (score 0):

In your loadSize method

```
loadSize() {
    this.campaignsService.getTotalNumberCampaigns().subscribe(value => {//async call
        this.campaignSize = value;
    }, (err)=> {}

    );
}
```

you should get the respone code by

```
value.status
```