# Why my error in subscirbe(()=>{},err=>{here}) is different from the error in browser console

Tags: angular

This is `loadSize()` function and it calls a `getTotalNumberCampaigns()` function in my `campaignsService` class.

```
 loadSize() {
    this.campaignsService.getTotalNumberCampaigns().subscribe(value => {//async call
        this.campaignSize = value;
    }, (err: any) => { console.log(err.status); console.log(err);}

    );
}
```

this is my getTotalNumberCampaigns()

```
 getTotalNumberCampaigns(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/Count`, { headers: this.headers })
        .map<any>(res => res.json())
}
```

I start up the backend api everything works fine, now I stop the api and refresh my page. It will fire the `console.log(err.status);` console.log(err); since it's connection failed. but I actually got 200 status while in my browser console it says it is a 502 error.

anyone tell me why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in the case of a connection failure, the response object you receive in your error callback is an error one since the value of its `type` attribute is `3` (`ERROR`). What is a bit strange is that it seems that the preflighted request is executed and received a response. Could you give us its details from the Network tab in dev tools (by clicking on "OPTIONS http://localhost:...")?

See this question for more details:

- [Get error message from Angular 2 http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669087/get-error-message-from-angular-2-http/35670089#35670089)