# Angular 2 catching 401 response

Tags: node.js, rest, http, angular, service

working on Angular2/Node.

For loggin in we have the following

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', { email: username, password: password })
  .map((response: Response) => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response

    let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
    if (token) {
      // set token property
      this.token = token;

      // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
      // return true to indicate successful login
      return true;
    } else {
      // return false to indicate failed login
      return false;
    }
  }).catch(err =>{
    if (err.status === 401)
    {
      console.log("caught 401 exception");
      return false;
    }
  });
```

problem being that i get the following error

> Argument of type '(err: any) => boolean' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable) =>
>   ObservableInput'.   Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type
>   'ObservableInput'.

And I'm unsure of what I need to change to get it to be able to catch the 401s

For testing the login looks as following

```
this.webapiService.login("Donald@geek.com","moneyIsGood").subscribe(result => {
  if (result === true) {
    console.log('Username or password is correct');
  } else {
    console.log('Username or password is incorrect');
  }
});
```

edit: Seems I'm missing a point about using .catch and subscribe together, but still unsure of how and why.

Comment: can you check this : [Angular2 : HTTP error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628498/angular2-http-error-handling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete this code:

```
.catch(err =>{
    if (err.status === 401)
    {
      console.log("caught 401 exception");
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Or add logging and throwing exception instead:

```
.catch(err => {
       console.log("caught exception" + err.status);
       return Observable.throw(err);
 });
```

Also add in subscribe:

```
this.webapiService.login("Donald@geek.com","moneyIsGood").subscribe(result => {
     console.log('Username or password is correct');
   }, error => {
      if (error.status === 401){
        console.log('Username or password is incorrect');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the error like that

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', { email: username, password: password })
.catch((error: any) => this.handleError(error))
.map((response: Response) => {
```