# Angular2: check file existance with http.get

Tags: angular

I have a simple method to check if a `*.mp3` file in my local machine exists or not.
**It is supposed to return the** `status` of the response (200, 404,403,etc), but it doesn't work.

```
fileExists(url){
        return this.http.get(url).timeout(2000)
                                 .map(res=>res.json())
                                 .subscribe(
                                           res=>{
                                                 console.log("res is");
                                                 console.log(res.status)
                                                 return res.status;},
                                           err =>{ 
                                                  console.log("Error is");
                                                   console.log(err.status); 
                                                   return err.status});

  }
```

I set a timeout for 2 seconds for it, however it only needs to check a file in my localhost. Therefore, i think, it has enough time to find the file.

it returns always:

```
Subscriber {closed: false, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false…}
```

Comment: the status returned is defined by you in the backend. no?

Comment: No, it is the status of http request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628498/angular2-http-error-handling

Comment: @Salman, and what backend framework are u using? if you are using a backend like apache, then you are leaving it to apache to give you the status, if you are using a backend like nodejs/django, you probably need to define how the file is fetched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to compose an observable that emits the status code of a `GET` request, you can do this:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

this.http.get("/some-file.txt")
    .map((response) => response.status)
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(error.status || 404))
    .subscribe((status) => console.log(`status = ${status}`));
```

And if you want to more efficiently determine the existence of a file based on a HTTP status code, you could use the `HEAD` method, which won't retrieve the file's content:

```ts
this.http.head("/some-file.txt")
    .map((response) => response.status)
    .catch((error) => Observable.of(error.status || 404))
    .subscribe((status) => console.log(`status = ${status}`));
```

The problem with the code in your question is that you are looking for JSON content in the response and are looking for the `status` within that content. The `status` is in the response itself.

However, to implement a function that determines file existence, you don't even need to examine the `status`:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

getFileStatus(path: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.http.head(path)
        .mapTo(true)
        .catch((error) => Observable.of(false))
        .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: but it does not return anything. I need it to return a boolean if it finds the file with status 200

Comment: You cannot return anything from within the `subscribe` callbacks; it just doesn't work like that. You can use the `toPromise` operator to convert the composed observable into a promise. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can this be used for checking file exist and if not exist to load other file, thank you.