# Setting default svg icon fallback in angular mat-icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular mat-icon with custom svg icon. I'm rendering the svg icon dynamically. Now in-case if the actual svg icon is missing, how can I set a default(static) svg icon.

Something similar to onError attr in img tag.

Thanks,
Shihad

```
html:
<mat-icon svgIcon="{{row.username}}" //default_svg_icon_src// ></mat-icon>

component:
  this.users.forEach(user => {
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      user.username,
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/icons/"+user.username+".svg")
    );
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to check if the icon exists before passing it to the registry, and then passing your fallback icon instead if it does not.

You could do this either via a http request or creating a new image element and binding to the `onload` and `onerror` functions.

Example using http:

*app.component.html*

```
<div *ngIf="iconsLoaded">
  <div *ngFor = "let user of users">
    <mat-icon [svgIcon]="user"></mat-icon>
    <span>{{user}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent  {
  users = ['user1','user2','user3','user4']
  iconsLoaded:boolean
  constructor(private iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private http:HttpClient){
    this.addUserIcons()
  }

  async addUserIcons(){
    for(let user of this.users){
      const iconPath = await this.getIconPathWithFallback(user)
      this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(user, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(iconPath));
    }
    // let the dom know when all icons have been loaded and block attempt rendering before (e.g. via *ngIf)
    this.iconsLoaded=true
  }

  // use a get request to see if the svg exists, if not return a default svg
  async getIconPathWithFallback(user:string){
      const iconPath = `assets/icons/${user}.svg`
      const response = await this.http.head(iconPath,{responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise()
      // if the svg icon is found the response will have type svg. If file not found returns html
      console.log('response type',response.type)
      return response.type === 'image/svg+xml' ? iconPath : 'assets/icons/default.svg'
  }   
}
```

Here is a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppbzvn

*Output*
[image: example output]

If you were to use a standard `<img>` tag instead of `<mat-icon>` it would be possible to just bind to the `onerror` call directly to replace the url if the image can't be found. This is discussed in another post here:

[how can i check if image exists in assets folder using angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282727/how-can-i-check-if-image-exists-in-assets-folder-using-angular-4)
and
[Angular2: check file existance with http.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543819/angular2-check-file-existance-with-http-get)

Comment: Tried the http request, but not getting any response.    `this.users.forEach(user => {
        let iconName = user.username; 
        if(!this.checkAssetExists(iconName)) {
          iconName = "default";
        } 
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
          user.username,
          this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/icons/"+iconName+".svg")
        );
      })`

Comment: `async checkAssetExists(iconName) {
    try {
      await this.http.get("../assets/icons/"+iconName+".svg", {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise()
      return true
  }
    catch(error) {
      return false
    }
  }`

Comment: Very strange, although I've realised an extra caveta is that even a failed request will return a text response (html). Have created a working stackblitz and will update answer above

Comment: My bad..! I used the promise directly in checking the boolean condition. Now I tried the `then` method on the promise object to get the actual boolean value and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer has 2 major problems:

1. it proposes in fact to register the icons asynchronously - so the consuming component must wait for the registration to have been completed, otherwise the icons will not be rendered (and of course waiting is bad for performance)
2. it's not scalable: imagine we have a very large number of icons we wish to register - then we have a very large number of HTTP requests just for registering the icons.

A better solution: use an interceptor!

```
@Injectable()
export class SvgFallbackInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const regex = /\.svg$/;
        const isSvg = regex.test(req.url);

        if (isSvg) {
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                    const defaultResponse = new HttpResponse({
                        body:       `<svg> ...[your default svg]...</svg>`,
                        headers:    err.headers,
                        status:     200, // or perhaps 302?
                        statusText: 'OK',
                        url:        err.url,
                    });

                    return of(defaultResponse);
                })
            );
        }
        else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

[read more about Angular interceptors here](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)