# Read response header from API

Tags: laravel, angular, jwt, angular2-services

How do I read response header from Laravel JWT in angular2?
I refer to [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941836/angular2-handling-http-response) but the `res` does not have `authorization` to read new JWT Token return from API.

Edit: It is the same issue with https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237#issuecomment-214610594

Comment: you want to get `Header` when you call API ? use `res.headers` while mapping function, see here in console http://plnkr.co/edit/tPzBPc4r8lx4mTo1BDcK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the plnkr. I have the same issue with this, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237#issuecomment-214610594 header in postman is not the same as in angular2

Comment: your welcome have you done with your problem ?

Comment: no.. not yet. Added `Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers' : "*"` to laravel `htaccess` doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of CORS. You're only be able to see the header in the map only if it's enabled by CORS.

Your server needs to return the following in headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-SomeHeader
```

Comment: currently using Laravel 5.2 on Nginx, where do you suggested me to put this line?