# Can RxJs chaining for Angular2 Http responses be made conditional?

Tags: conditional-statements, rxjs

I'm new to RxJs and Angular2, and I'm trying to properly handle errors. I've seen some examples with Observables that have onNext, onError and onCompleted events (e.g. [here](http://paqmind.com/posts/rxjs-error-and-completed-events-demystified/), but all of the Angular2 http examples that I see seem to just use .catch and .map methods, and I'm not sure how that relates to the OnNext/OnError/OnCompleted model. I'm working with the code from [here](https://blog.sstorie.com/adapting-ben-nadels-apigateway-to-pure-typescript/)):

```
let stream = this.http.request(options.url, options)
     .catch(error: any) => {
        this.errorsSubject.next(error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
     })
    .map(this.unwrapHttpValue)
    .catch((error: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(this.unwrapHttpError(error));
    });
```

I initially wanted to just make it so that the first .catch and the .map are either/or? (i.e. the .map only runs if the http request is successful), but I'm not sure if that's even possible, and then it was further complicated by my reading the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941836/angular2-handling-http-response) where it seems like they may be saying that per [this fix](https://github.com/robwormald/angular/commit/cf338e8ec7cc8cfbe6e66eae51e271ee825c891f), the map method will automatically be skipped if the HTTP code is <200 or >300...? However, that isn't what I'm observing in practice with angular 2.0.0-rc.4...

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of `catch` being like typical `try` and `catch` code.  For an observable, all of the operations will be run in order as if they were in a `try` block.  If there is an error, then processing will jump down to the first `catch`.

So, if you only want to run the `map` on success, then you just put it *before* the `catch`:

```
let stream = this.http.request(options.url, options)
    .map(this.unwrapHttpValue)
    .catch(error: any) => {
       this.errorsSubject.next(error);
       return Observable.throw(error);
    });
```