# Angular 4.0.0 http service does not throw error automatically when status is 403

Tags: angular, angular-http

As I've read in another stackoverflow answer - from Angular 2 alpha 47 - http service should throw error automatically when response status field is larger than 299. My question is on what stage?

I've got http response with status 403, but service seems to allow to execute all map() methods. Why doesn't it redirect response to catch block?

```
getLoggedInUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + `api/user/me`)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      console.log(res.status); <-- 403
      return res.json();
   })
   .map((user: User) => new User().deserialize(user)) <-- This method shouldn't be fired, because it causes unexpected behaviour.
   .catch((error: any) => { 
      console.log(error);
      if (error.status === 403) {
        this.isRequestForbidden = true;
      } 
      return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error') 
  });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular aspect of Angular might be changed since early alpha versions. And with version `4.3+` they introduced completely new http service that replacing the old one.

So why wouldn't you just check `403` status inside your first `.map()` and throw an error there or something. But based on that [commit](https://github.com/robwormald/angular/commit/cf338e8ec7cc8cfbe6e66eae51e271ee825c891f) this should not be a case.

> In case if you are on the latest angular like `4.3+` make sure you are
>   using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) from `@anghular/common/http`

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0 (edited title). Is it necessary to check the status manually there as well? It seems to me ununderstandable why we go back after introducing auto feature earlier? Are you sure is it the only one solution or is something in this code not perfect/forgotten?

Comment: what do you mean by saying `change the status manually` ? did you actually mean  `check the status manually` ?

Comment: I didn't mean especially 403 status code. Just thought that status greater than 299 is taking into account as @Eric Martinez suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941836/angular2-handling-http-response

Comment: Okay. Please come back. I also posted another (broader) question concerning the right approach to error handling in Angular 4 http requests at all. On the same example. I'd greatly appreciate if you are able to propose a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879364/how-to-appropriately-handle-error-responses-angular-4-0-0