# How to appropriately handle error responses Angular 4.0.0

Tags: angular, angular-http

I've got a problem with handling errors in Angular 4. Please advice me the proper approach. When server respond with error I'd like to redirect it to cache block and there I'd like to have a specific behaviour when status is 403. When I check the status in the first map() and throw an error from there - catch block is executed, but error is passing as a string with stack trace. It makes unpossible to recognize status in catch block again. How to do it right way?

```
getLoggedInUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + `api/user/me`)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      if(res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        console.log(res.status);
        throw new Error();
      } 
      else {
        return res.json();
      }
    })
    .map((user) => {
      let deserializedUser = new User().deserialize(user)
      this._loggedInUser = deserializedUser;
      return deserializedUser;
    })
    .catch((errorStatus: any) => { 
      console.log(errorStatus.status);
      if (errorStatus === "403") {
        console.log(errorStatus);
        this.isRequestForbidden = true;
      }
      return Observable.throw(errorStatus || 'Server error') 
    });
}
```

Comment: If the status is not a success status, the first map callback shouldn't be executed in the first place. The first map callback should just return the json, nothing else. And if you switched to the new HttpClient module, you wouldn't even need it.

Comment: @JBNizet sounds like he gets the first `map()` executed on `403` for some reason.

Comment: @JBNizet exactly - I mainly suprised that first map() is even fired. Why this is happening?

Comment: @magos i think you are confusing .map with .subscribe. map always tries to map the data.

Comment: @Carsten - so how to process data in given situation to pass information about error status to catch method not in string?

Comment: @Carsten no, map() is not executed when the observable emits an error. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ge1MTck7inpSxuqR1Tb0?p=preview

Comment: @Carsten I think he is subscribing to his function like `cgetLoggedInUser().subscribe(...)` but why first `.map()` is getting called I am not sure. Tried to reproduce but using latest `4.3.5` referencing old `http` from `@angular/http` - no way first `.map()` is getting called - getting straight to `.catch()` on `403` status code

Comment: so just downgraded to angular 4.0.0 an guess what - just going straight to `.catch()` block @magos can you reproduce your error online?