# Register error function in a GET http request

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-get

I do not know how to handle the error case for a `GET` API call. **Please update my snippet to handle the scenario where API call fails.**

*code snippet*

```or-tag-here
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { 
  }

  getPostData(){
   return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").map((res:Response) => res.json());   
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941836/angular2-handling-http-response

Answer (score 1):

```
this.PostsService.getPostData(params).subscribe(
        data =>
        {
            //data that has come back from the api
        },
        err =>
        {
           // err will be any errors responces from the API 
        }
    );
```

you can then handle your error however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

use `err callback` for this.

**conponent.ts**

```
constructor(private postsService:PostsService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.postsService.getPostData().subscribe(res =>{
        console.log(res)
    },err =>{
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

**Step 2:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { 
  }

  getPostData(){
   return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);   
  }

 handleError(err){
  //Observable.throw(err);
 }
```

}

And then when you subscribe :

```
this._yourService.getPostData().subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res);
},err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    1 ) Make a different Service file where you can call rest APIs.

    2) And make a call from your component by injection the services.


    **For Example, Assume  this is Service file assume ->**

     getEvents(response) {

        let accesstoken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

        let headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accesstoken);

        let url = this.baseUrl + 'getEventListingToAdmin?page=' + response.page + '&perPage=10';

        var data = this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});

        return data;
      }


    **And This is a Component Part -->**

     first import the service file in component 

    import { AdminService }      from  '../../admin.service';

    **Then Inject it in constructor**

      constructor(private admin: AdminService) { }

    ngOnInit  () {
    this.admin.getEvents(response)
          .subscribe(
            (data:any) => {

//USE CAN USE HERE LOADS
              this.loading = false;

// CAN CHECK THE RESPONSE STATUS
              if(data.statusCode==200){
                this.managersData = data.data.EventData;
                this.allItems     = data.data.EventCount;
              }

            },
            error => {
//USE CAN USE HERE LOADS
              this.loading = false;

// CAN CHECK THE RESPONSE STATUS
              if(error.error.statusCode===401)
{
// CAN ADD SWEET ALERT
 Swal(
                  error.error.msg,
                  'error'
                )
}


            });
    }
```